# Link "responder" em comentários

Tags: novo-recurso, comentários, usuarios

Bem que os comentários poderiam ter um link "responder", assim como no chat. Ao clicar neste link, `@nomeDoUsuárioQueEscreveuOComentário` já viria escrito.

Comment: Boa idéia! Seria legal fazer um *mockup* de como seria isso, tipo um ícone pequeno junto do upvote/flag ou então do lado do delete... Assim os Devs e Community Managers entenderão sem precisar de muita tradução.

Comment: Concordo com o mockup, mas ainda tenho dúvidas sobre a necessidade do recurso.

Comment: Eu acho que esse recurso não existe para desincentivar que a discussão nos comentários se alongue. Comentários são cidadãos de segunda classe na rede, e são frequentemente apagados, pelos próprios autores e por moderadores. As informações importantes devem ser incluídas na própria pergunta ou resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo, "As informações importantes devem ser incluídas na própria pergunta ou resposta", mas as vezes um comentário sob a questão abre espaço para maior entendimento de uma questão mal formulada.

Comment: Se não me engano tem um script no StackApps que coloca esse link.

Answer (score 5):

Existe um userscript pra isso, [**“Reply” links on comments**](https://stackapps.com/q/2051/10590):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sou favorável ao link de responder, mas também vejo que existe uma "tensão" entre a finalidade e o uso que se faz dos comentários.

Uma coisa é a idealização da finalidade de um recurso, e outra é o uso que é feito dele de forma consagrada por uma comunidade. Se as pessoas utilizam de uma determinada forma, é porque sentem necessidade disso na plataforma.

Pelo que observo, acredito que seria muito melhor se os comentários fossem de algum modo transferidos para uma outra aba na própria pergunta sob a forma de "discussão", como é comum em wikis. Obviamente seria uma mudança muito profunda, mas creio que valha a pena pensar nisso.

Aliás, esta resposta é um exemplo do problema: depois do primeiro parágrafo, tudo poderia ser outra pergunta ou um comentário, mas comentários não são local de discussão, e como isso não é uma pergunta, restam apenas os comentários para discutir minha resposta.

Comment: Gosto da ideia. O sistema já faz um pouco isso, ao sugerir que discussões longas sejam migradas para o chat. Existe também uma **[proposta de estender essa funcionalidade](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100967/should-move-to-chat-be-provided-on-demand-as-a-button-perhaps)**.